# Trying to reference other cells in a worksheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to apply a formula in one worksheet to another. This is my code so far:

```
.Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(Forecasts!E4,""-"",Forecasts!E3)"
```

This code works, however, the formula in the formula bar is different than what I wanted. In the formula bar, I have the formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(Forecasts!'E4',"-",Forecasts!'E3')
```

Notice the quotes around E4 and E3 which were not in my VBA code. How do I get rid of these quotes.

Thanks,

G

Comment: change `.FormulaR1C1` for `.Formula`

Comment: You could also just have "=Forecasts!E4&""-""&Forecasts!E3"

Comment: If you want to keep R1C1 ref style you could write `.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(Forecasts!R[2]C[4] & "" - "" &Forecasts!R[1]C[4])"`